# What does this complex integral mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

is 2i the the area of the semi circle? The area of semi circle in R^2 is pi/2 for a circle of radius 1.

Comment: Why would that integral give you the area of a semicircle? You could interpret it as $i$ times the area under one half-wave of a sine curve (and the real part is the integral of a cosine, which vanishes), but that is not semicircle-shaped.

Comment: The integral is a contour integral of the constant function f(z)=1/i, over a semi-circle in the complex plane. I provided a derivation in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3):

The expression in your question is the contour integral of the constant function
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{i}$$
over the semi-circle $C$ of radius $1$ centered at $0$ in the complex plane.

$$\oint_C f(z)dz$$
Lets calculate
$$z=e^{it}\implies dz=ie^{it}dt$$
Thus
$$\oint_C \frac{1}{i}dz=\int_0^\pi e^{it}dt=2i$$